# Plotting a graph of a square root function does not show the expected graph

Tags: plotting

New to Mathematica and have been given some assignments for practice.

I am currently trying to plot the following function:

$$|\sqrt{x-1}+5|$$

This is how other sites show what this graph should look like:

[image: Example graph]

But trying to plot the same function in Mathematica gives the following unexpected graph:

[image: unexpected graph]

That straight line coming in from the left shouldn't be there, and no matter how I try to re-organize the plot function it seems to stay.

Am I misunderstanding something? Am I using the `Plot` function wrong? Thanks for any help and apologies if this is a noob question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `RealAbs` instead of `Abs`  since `Abs` is a `Complex` function.
And the `Sqrt` is also a `Complex` function, sometimes we use `Surd` instead of `Sqrt` or `Power`

if we assume `x` is a real numbers,we can use `ComplexExpand` to observe the expression of `Abs[Sqrt[x - 1] + 5]`

```
Abs[Sqrt[x - 1] + 5] // ComplexExpand

(*  Sqrt[(5 + ((-1 + x)^2)^(1/4) Cos[1/2 Arg[-1 + x]])^2 + 
 Sqrt[(-1 + x)^2] Sin[1/2 Arg[-1 + x]]^2] *)
```

So we had to use another way.

```
Plot[RealAbs[Surd[x-1,2]+5],{x,-5,5},AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: Amazing comment, thanks for the help! My whole study group appreciates it.